# Importing a single function from a module in VB.Net

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, winforms, namespaces

I was wondering if I can import a single function like python without importing all the other things like python does:

```
from prog1 import func
```

Answer (score 1):

In VB you need to do two things to able to use a function or anything else declared in another assembly or namespace.

1. Add a reference to the assembly (*.dll, *.exe).
2. Import the namespace. E.g. `Imports System.Drawing`.

Then you can use all the things in there.

Instead of using an `Imports` statement you can also specify the namespace directly. Example:

```
'Without Imports
Dim image As System.Drawing.Image
image = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(myImagefile)
```

With `Imports System.Drawing` at the top of the code:

```
Dim image As Image
image = New Bitmap(myImagefile)
```

The most important assemblies are already referenced and the most often used namespaces imported implicitly. These namespaces are list in the project properties under *References*.

Note that you cannot import single functions, you always have to reference a whole assembly. The `Imports` does not influence the resources used. It only makes it handier to access things. They reduce typing.

Note also, that the standard .NET libraries of the .NET Framework are installed on the system and are already compiled. They are not imported physically into your project, they are only referenced. I.e., using them does not make your application bigger.

Comment: What's the difference between import and dim "import" (I'm interested in terms of resource usage, but generally too)

Comment: `Dim` is only used as an example.

Comment: So there isn't any functional difference between import something and dim XYZ as something.else other then the latter requiring more letters (especially if used multiple times)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The resulting compiled code is exactly the same in both cases.

Comment: My actual concern was about having a functon with same name as another function the referenced module from where I want to use a third function. If I import the module then I would also import the same-named function. If I don't qualify that function will the one I defined in the importing module be called or the one in the imported module ?

Comment: This is the motivation behind the namespaces. If there is a conflict, you can remove the `Imports` and specify the namespaces directly or you can define aliases. See also [Imports Statement (.NET Namespace and Type)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/imports-statement-net-namespace-and-type).

Comment: @beppe9000 If you don't want to type a long namespace every time you need to distinguish between duplicate method names, you can use and alias.  `Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`